# Duplicate sources.list entry but cannot find the duplicates?

Tags: duplicate, software-sources

I'm running 12.04 64bit, and every time I update using the command land, I always get

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/restricted amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/gb.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/restricted i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/gb.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_restricted_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/restricted amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/gb.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/gb.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_restricted_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

I've looked at loads of suggestions from previous problems including unselecting the sources from software sources, or manually removing the 'duplicates' manually from sources.list.

However, when trying to fix it, I've not found the duplicates highlighted anywhere? So I have no idea why this message keeps coming up.

The errors aren't causing anything detrimental to my system but it just looks a bit messy and I would like to know what's causing it.

Any ideas?

Thanks!