# Duplicate Sources

Tags: software-sources, duplicate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Duplicate sources.list entry but cannot find the duplicates?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156227/duplicate-sources-list-entry-but-cannot-find-the-duplicates)

How do I fix this? I tried doing the `apt-get update` but it didn't fix it.

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://apt.insynchq.com/ubuntu/ quantal/non-free i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/apt.insynchq.com_ubuntu_dists_quantal_non-free_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

I must have added it twice somehow. This is my first time using Ubuntu so I am still learning.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I would run `grep -rn "apt.insynchq.com" /etc/apt`. It will show you which files contain the specified text, and if so, on which line in that file.